# Drag And drop FloatingActionButton Android

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I am tryng use drag and drop in a FAB, but my drop action never called;

**Here is my drag activation code:**

```
View.OnLongClickListener onDrag = new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);
            v.getClass();
            v.startDrag(ClipData.newPlainText("test", "test"), shadowBuilder, v, 0);
            return true;
        }
    };
```

**And here the listner:**

```
protected class myDragEventListener implements View.OnDragListener {

    // This is the method that the system calls when it dispatches a drag event to the
    // listener.
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {

        // Defines a variable to store the action type for the incoming event
        final int action = event.getAction();
        switch (action) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                return true;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                //v.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                return true;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                return true;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
                //v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                return false;
            // return processDragStarted(event);
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                Toast.makeText(context, "teste ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();;
            default:
                return true;

        }
    }
```

**and i am setting in my fab: (setOnClickListener and setOnDragListener  )**

Answer (score 0):

You're setting your `OnLongClickListener` incorrectly.

You should be using `setOnLongClickListener()`, not `setOnClickListener()`.